# Javafx: get Property from TableCell

Tags: java, javafx, properties, javafx-8, tablecell

I want to get a property from a model in my TableCell, so I can maipulate the cell depending on that property lets se the following example:

I have a model like:

```
public class Model {

    private CustomProperty<Integer> appleCount;
    private CustomProperty<Integer> peachCount;

    public Model(Integer appleCount, Integer peachCount) {
        this.appleCount = new CustomIntegerProperty(appleCount);
        this.peachCount = new CustomIntegerProperty(peachCount);
    }

    public CustomProperty<Integer> appleCountProperty() {
        return appleCount;
    }

    public CustomProperty<Integer> peachCountProperty() {
        return peachCount;
    }
}
```

**This model is just a mock of that I have, and I have a few models which have two or more `CustomProperty<Integer>`**

Then I have a few tables that has this `Model` or a similar class as model of the `TableView`. I have a custom `TableCell` with overriden `updateItem` and there I want to set the cell's text depending on the properties that `CustomProperty` has for example initialValue, oldValue, etc.Fo example if the initialValue is 0 then set the text empty instead of the *0* that has the cell by default. I have a partial solution for it: creating an `interface HasCustomProperty` then the Model would implement it, but then there are a few problems:

- I need to add two CustomProperties or a list of them to the interface
- I need to ask somehow in the cell: *Are you the appleCount?* or *Are you the peach cell?*

It is sure that in one cell there is only one property, the apple or the peach, so theoretically I should not care about in the cell if I know both of them are CustomIntegerProperties so I know they have `initialValue` or `oldValue` so I can set the cell's text depending on it.

I can only get the item, which is a type of Integer, so I don't have the properties of it or is there any way to get the property itself?

A sollution could be to override in every column's cellFactory the updateItem, and there I know for instance this is the appleColumn so get the information from the appleCountProperty, and so on, but this causes a lot of duplicate code if I have to do it in 5-6 places. So I thought I make a custom TableCell and there I manage the text, then I just set for every column that cell for `cellFactory()`.

Do you have any Idea how can I do it simple without duplicate code?

Comment: I wasn't quite sure exactly the question you are asking....  I provided an answer on how to give the cell the cell the entire object for query during update item.  If this is not what you are looking for, Please let me know and I can hopefully point you in a different direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion - I think the issue you are facing is determining the difference between a user set 0 and an initialized 0 of an IntegerProperty.

Rather than use IntegerProperty which uses int and can't be null - you should use the following in the model:

```
private ObjectProperty<Integer> appleCountProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
```

Then in your table you just bind to it:

```
@FXML
TableColumn<Model, Integer> appleCountColumn;
```

//In your initialize

```
appleCountColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().appleCountProperty ());
```

This should give you what you need.

Comment: I know this can be a solution, but the problem is if I use this solution I will have duplicate codes, because I have a few model classes, that are similar, and theyhas a `CustomProperty<Integer>`, then I will have to do this in many places. What I want a custom table cell that handles all `CustomProperty<Integer>`-s in one place then for every column I can simply call `.setCellFactory(factory -> new CustomIntegerTableCell())`

Comment: Are you just trying to leave the cell blank when it's 0?  I don't understand why you need to query the cell in this way - I need to ask somehow in the cell: Are you the appleCount? or Are you the peach cell?

Comment: So yes, I want to use integer values, but when I initially construct the rows I want to be empties not initialized with 0-s. But later if I set a value to 0 then the 0 should be displayed.

Comment: I changed to show how to set a 0 to "" in a custom cell - but how do you know in your model that the 0 is a real 0 rather than a default?  Your question doesn't detail how you know that the field has been set by the user?

Comment: Okay but if I use this way a cannot change the value to 0 anymore if I want.

Comment: How do you know when you want to use 0?  That is the question - can you tell me how you know?  Usually you assume null would be blank and 0 would be a valid value - your use case states I need 0 to be blank unless I set it to 0 - but something on the model needs to know if the value was actually set to 0.

Comment: I want to be empty initially. Then later if I want to put there as value 0, I should be able to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150322/discussion-between-purring-pigeon-and-sunflame).